# Chromeの拡張機能作成について

Tags: chrome-extension

こんにちは。まだコードを一ミリも書いていないのですが質問させていただきます

Chromeの拡張機能で以下のようなものを作りたいのですが、作れますか。

①classroomで添付されたドキュメント・Spreadsheetなどを押す
②メールアドレスを自動収集し、投稿者にのみ、既読者のメールアドレスを表示する
　→これを作りたい

作れますか？作れるのであれば使用言語を教えて下さい。
情報がとにかく必要です。小さなことでも教えて下さい。
よろしくお願いいたします

Answer (score 0):

メールアドレスを取得しなきゃいけないのは拡張機能だと厳しいと思います。(まあ頑張って[スクレイピング](https://w.wiki/3uZv)なりなんなりをすればいけますが。)上記のようなことを実現したいのであれば[GAS](https://Google%20Apps%20Script)でかんたんに実現できると思います。
仮にGASで作るとします。スプレッドシート側に閲覧者のメールアドレスを取得したければ

```
Session.getActiveUser().getUserLoginId()
```

で、メールを送信したければ

```
GmailApp.sendEmail()
```

で実現できます。

Comment: 当方ドキュメントでやっているのですがSession.getActiveUser().getUserLoginId()で実行するとemail:''と表示されてしまいます。

Comment: 質問の方にコードを貼り付けていただくことは可能でしょうか？